# Set ylim while labeling breaks

Tags: ggplot2

I have data like this:

```
df<-structure(list(PreConfidenceMarginal = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1), PostConfidenceMarginal = c(2, 
2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3), NoMarginalRepairs = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I've made this graph with it:

```
df%>%pivot_longer(!NoMarginalRepairs, names_to = "Time", values_to = "Value")%>%group_by(Time,NoMarginalRepairs)%>%summarize(Mean=mean(Value),SD=sd(Value, na.rm = TRUE))%>%mutate(Time=as.factor(Time))%>%mutate(Time=fct_recode(Time,"Pre-Workshop"="PreConfidenceMarginal","Post-Workshop"="PostConfidenceMarginal"))%>%mutate(Time = factor(Time, levels = c("Pre-Workshop", "Post-Workshop")))%>%ggplot(aes(x=Time,y=Mean,color=NoMarginalRepairs,group=NoMarginalRepairs))+geom_point()+geom_line()+labs(color="Has not repaired any marginal eyelid lacerations",title = "Degree of Improvement", subtitle = "Repairing Marginal Lid Laceration" , y= "Confidence Level")+scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4,5),labels = c("1. Poor", "2. Fair", "3. Good", "4. Very Good", "5. Excellent"))
```

[image]

Looks great and is mostly what I want.  That being said I'd love the y axis to go from 1 to at least 4, and when I try to do that with ylim I'm having trouble.

When I use only ylim() and not the custom breaks and labels, works fine:

```
df%>%pivot_longer(!NoMarginalRepairs, names_to = "Time", values_to = "Value")%>%group_by(Time,NoMarginalRepairs)%>%summarize(Mean=mean(Value),SD=sd(Value, na.rm = TRUE))%>%mutate(Time=as.factor(Time))%>%mutate(Time=fct_recode(Time,"Pre-Workshop"="PreConfidenceMarginal","Post-Workshop"="PostConfidenceMarginal"))%>%mutate(Time = factor(Time, levels = c("Pre-Workshop", "Post-Workshop")))%>%ggplot(aes(x=Time,y=Mean,color=NoMarginalRepairs,group=NoMarginalRepairs))+geom_point()+geom_line()+labs(color="Has not repaired any marginal eyelid lacerations",title = "Degree of Improvement", subtitle = "Repairing Marginal Lid Laceration" , y= "Confidence Level")+ylim(1,4)
```

[image]

But when I try to have both in my code like so it messes up:

```
df%>%filter(!is.na(NoMarginalRepairs))%>%select(PreConfidenceMarginal,PostConfidenceMarginal,NoMarginalRepairs)%>%pivot_longer(!NoMarginalRepairs, names_to = "Time", values_to = "Value")%>%group_by(Time,NoMarginalRepairs)%>%summarize(Mean=mean(Value),SD=sd(Value, na.rm = TRUE))%>%mutate(Time=as.factor(Time))%>%mutate(Time=fct_recode(Time,"Pre-Workshop"="PreConfidenceMarginal","Post-Workshop"="PostConfidenceMarginal"))%>%mutate(Time = factor(Time, levels = c("Pre-Workshop", "Post-Workshop")))%>%ggplot(aes(x=Time,y=Mean,color=NoMarginalRepairs,group=NoMarginalRepairs))+geom_point()+geom_line()+labs(color="Has not repaired any marginal eyelid lacerations",title = "Degree of Improvement", subtitle = "Repairing Marginal Lid Laceration" , y= "Confidence Level")+scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4,5),labels = c("1. Poor", "2. Fair", "3. Good", "4. Very Good", "5. Excellent"))+ylim(1,4)
```

It tells me why (and it makes sense):

"Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale."

But how do I do both?  Change the labels on the data and at the same time ensure that the scale goes far enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the limits via the `limits` argument of `scale_y_continuous`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(!NoMarginalRepairs, names_to = "Time", values_to = "Value") %>%
  group_by(Time, NoMarginalRepairs) %>%
  summarize(Mean = mean(Value), SD = sd(Value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(Time = as.factor(Time)) %>%
  mutate(Time = fct_recode(Time, "Pre-Workshop" = "PreConfidenceMarginal", "Post-Workshop" = "PostConfidenceMarginal")) %>%
  mutate(Time = factor(Time, levels = c("Pre-Workshop", "Post-Workshop"))) 

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = Time, y = Mean, color = NoMarginalRepairs, group = NoMarginalRepairs)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  labs(color = "Has not repaired any marginal eyelid lacerations", 
       title = "Degree of Improvement", 
       subtitle = "Repairing Marginal Lid Laceration", 
       y = "Confidence Level") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                     labels = c("1. Poor", "2. Fair", "3. Good", "4. Very Good", "5. Excellent"), 
                     limits = c(1, 4))
```

[image]